# fetching all product from my data base too slow with hibernate "EGER"

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa, ejb-3.0

hi i am using JPA hibernate as  a persistance framwork 
all fetc type atribute on my class are EAGER , so when i am ettempting to find ALL product from my data Base it take 15 second , too slow :( 
is there a solution to accelerate it , i want to have  all my product with all dependencies , i have  juste 80 row  on my mysql DB , is it logic  all this time ? 
can i moderate this  type  of fetching 
i am using EJB3.0 the session productSession is statless and  i am using a named query
      @NamedQuery(name = "Produit.findAll", query = "select a from Produit a")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you set everything association to eager, it will obviously take a lot of time, because when loading a product, its category must be fetched. And the creator of the category. And the brother of the creator. And the daughter of the brother. And the company of the daughter. And the city of the company. And the country of the city, etc. etc. And I'm not even talking about to-many associations.

Just don't set everything to eager loaded. And use appropriate HQL queries to only load what you're interested in. If an association is set to eager, it will ALWAYS be eagerly loaded. If you set it to lazy, it can be fetched eagerly when you want to, using an HQL or Criteria query.

Read the [HQL documentation about joins](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#queryhql-joins), and especially fetch joins.